# What is "orthogonality" in the context of Instruction Encoding?

Tags: computer-architecture, encoding-scheme, assembly

What does it mean by "orthogonality" in the context of Instruction Encoding?

Why CISC Architecture is orthogonal while RISC is not?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_instruction_set